# How to change the width of lines in a PDF/PostScript file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I regularly need to handle technical drawings (mechanical engineering) and they often come with colored lines, which can't be printed properly. Therefore I wrote the batch script listed below. It uses ghostscript to convert drawings to black & white; note that greyscales aren't sufficient, as they might be barely visible on a laser print.
The batch script even handles multiple files dragged and dropped on it.

**Now I encounter a large bunch of drawings which appear to have linewidths of hairline – hardly visible on a laser print.**

I tried to adopt the script but to no avail!

I tried

```
-c "save /zz {setlinewidth} bind def /setlinewidth { 10 mul zz} bind def"

-c "/setlinewidth { 10 } bind"
```

among others.

What are the correct parameters for ghostscript to change the linewidths?

I also attached the PostScript file I use to experiment with.

Thank you very much!!!

L.

```
::  PDFmono.bat
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto :eof

set GS_EXEC=gswin64c.exe

:loop

set INPUT_FILE=%1
set INTERMEDIATE_FILE=%temp%\%~n1.ps
set OUTPUT_FILE=%~dp1\%~n1_mono%~x1
echo ==============================================================================
echo Converting PDF to monochrome:
echo %INPUT_FILE%
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%GS_EXEC% ^
    -sOutputFile="%INTERMEDIATE_FILE%" ^
    -sDEVICE=ps2write ^
    -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER ^
    "%INPUT_FILE%"

%GS_EXEC% ^
    -sOutputFile="%OUTPUT_FILE%" ^
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
    -c "/setrgbcolor { pop pop pop 0 setgray } def /setcmykcolor { pop pop pop pop 0 setgray } def /sethsbcolor { pop pop pop 0 setgray } def" ^
    -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER ^
    "%INTERMEDIATE_FILE%"

del "%INTERMEDIATE_FILE%"
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Done! Monochrome PDF saved as
echo %OUTPUT_FILE%
echo ==============================================================================

shift
if not [%1]==[] goto loop
```

Comment: Seems I can't attach a file, yet posting it is too long by 174914 characters!?

Comment: If the script you're working on is too big to post here, cut it down until you have just the bare essentials needed for us to duplicate your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SomethingDark:
Thanks for the suggestion!
Unfortunately it's a PostScript file created by Ghostscript; I cannot manually shrink it.

Comment: @Compo
You're right, it's not a batch issue!
PostScript is a Turing-complete programming language, thus I think the question fits here.

Answer (score 2):

PDF and PostScript are different things, and it isn't clear to me which you are using as your input. If it's PDF then you basically can't change the width of lines. If it's PostScript then, within certain limits, you can.

First thing to note is that it's entirely possible (and not totally uncommon) for PostScript programs to deliberately defeat the kind of operator re-definition you are performing to change colour. A program can explicitly load the operators directly from systemdict, which will bypass your redefinition of the operators. Your definitions will be stored in userdict (because you haven't specified any other dictionary). You can't override the definitions in systemdict because that is read-only. You could use `-dWRITESYSTEMDICT` but I'd strongly recommend that you don't, because that's a massive security hole.

The reason your redefinition of setlinewidth doesn't work is almost certainly due to the fact that the PostScript program will be executing something like `0 setlinewidth`. This is defined in PostScript as drawing the narrowest possible line on the device, usually one pixel wide.

Looking at your two examples:

Multiplying 0 by 10 results in... zero! Which doesn't alter the line width. Note that you've also executed save, but not restore, which is wasteful. You don't need the save.

In the second example you've left the original parameter on the stack, so potentially corrupted the program execution, and you haven't actually altered the graphics state because you haven't called the system setlinewidth. Which also leaves the 10 on the stack.

Something like:

```
%% Grab a copy of the current setlinewidth
%%
/system_setlinewidth /setlinewidth load def

%% Define a version of setlinewidth which expands hairlines
%%
/setlinewidth {
  dup            %% copy the linewidth parameter
  0 eq           %% Test if its zero, defined as a hairline (consumes the copy)
  {
    pop 10       %% discard the linewidth and replace it with 10
  }
  system_setlinewidth  %% Still need to actually execute the setlinewidth
} bind def
```

Would probably work. Note that I haven't tested this.

The question is entirely on-topic for both Ghostscript and PostScript since it involves a PostScript programming question. Its not on-topic for 'monchrome', 'cmd', 'batch-file' and (probably) PDF.

There is no way to apply this trickery to a PDF file with Ghostscript though, and the same potential problem applies; zero width lines are defined as hairlines and are always one pixel wide, no matter what the resolution of the device. If you can you should recommend to the people creating these files that they don't do that unless they have an awfully good reason!

Comment: In my industry both issues – technical drawings in PDF format with colored lines and/or hairlines – are a common. The reason is that people plotting the CAD drawings to PDF files don't use (proper) pentable files (a legacy from pen plotters). You're right, I haven't clearly stated that the original files are (always) PDF files.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The monochrome issue is already solved. It converts a PDF file to PostScript using Ghostscript, saves this to the temporary directory. Then it calls Ghostscript again to save the PostScript back to a PDF, while executing
/setrgbcolor { pop pop pop 0 setgray } def /setcmykcolor { pop pop pop pop 0 setgray } def /sethsbcolor { pop pop pop 0 setgray } def

Maybe it doesn't work for all files, but it does for those I tried so far.

Comment: Well, if you're already happy doing that, then you can do the same thing for linewidths. Note that if any of your PDF files include transparency then things will go badly wrong. The page will be rendered to a bitmap which will result in a huge, slow file, where you won't be able to alter the colours or linewidth (because tehy'll be 'baked into' the image)

Comment: If ten should be the minimum drawn width, then `10 lt` might be a better test than `0 eq`.

Comment: 10 was a  number plucked at random, the 0 lt is so that it only expands **hairlines** ie cases where setlinewidth is set to 0, which means exactly one pixel on any device. Which is what the comment says ;-)